# Android 4.3 - webView load page with javascript, null pointer

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I have a null pointer exception when using webView with android 4.3, the code segment goes like this:

```
public WebView webview
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);


    // get data from previous activity
    getAllDataFromPreviousActivity();


    loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "loading page...");


    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);


    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);       
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "Html");


    // construct url
    this.modifiedUrl = constructURL();
    webView.loadUrl(modifiedUrl);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        // ignore SSL error
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }

         @Override
         public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
         {
           loadingDialog.show();
         }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        // check title to determine which view should be displayed
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            /* To check whether webView reached Authorization code page */
            loadingDialog.dismiss();

            if (view.getTitle().equals("XXXX")) {
                RelativeLayout ealLogin = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.login_view);
                ealLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
});
```

I use webClient to monitor the page title, when the title is XXXX, I will make the login layout visible and ask user to do some login stuff. (the "modifiedUrl" which webView loads is a https webpage with javascript embedded in the page source)

The app works like a charm on android 4.4 emulator. However, when I test it on my Samsung S3 actual device(Android 4.3) it will throw me a null pointer exception in OnPageFinish() method. It shows that the view.getTitle() will be null because here the "view" itself is null. I know it most likely is some problems with webView loading page with javascript in Android 4.3. Is there any way to solve this issue without upgrading to Android 4.4? Or is there way to walk around? Thanks for any help!!

Edited: 
activity_webView.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/webseal_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="username" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/webseal_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/access_token_in_settings"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/webseal_username"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:text="@string/Username"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:text="@string/WebSEALLogin"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/access_token_in_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/webseal_username"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="@string/Password"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/webseal_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/webseal_password"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:text="@string/Login"
        android:onClick="webSEALButtonPressed"
         />

</RelativeLayout>


<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</WebView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

my log:

05-26 14:46:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(29717): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 14:46:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(29717): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 14:46:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):
at com.example.ui.WebViewActivity$1.onPageFinished(WebViewActivity.java:120)
05-26 14:46:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:416)
05-26 14:46:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-26 14:46:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
05-26 14:46:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
05-26 14:46:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 14:46:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-26 14:46:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
05-26 14:46:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
05-26 14:46:21.070: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: post `activity_webview.xml` and the stacktrace

Comment: What is line 120 in `WebViewActivity.java`?

Comment: @Raghunandan it's if(view.getTitle.equals("xxxx")), so it is whether view.getTitle()gives me a null pointer or view itself is null. I did try to print view.getUrl(), but is still null, so I think view itself is null, am i right?

Comment: yes view is null no doubt

Comment: @Raghunandan you have any idea on why it is null?